# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) after resetting root password

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this when trying to load a webpage that requires the mysql database. I had to go and recently reset the root password that was used for phpmyadmin.

`oops connection problem ! --> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

All this is also running on my Raspberry Pi 2.

I used the below command after these issues  which only reset the root phpmyadmin password

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

I can also log in to mysql by using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the password in the configs of the webpage.

Please check your db credentials in the php page.

**Remember:**

If you include something that contains the db credentials you should change it there.

Comment: I will I have to wait 10 minutes after it being posted before I can do that. :P

Comment: hahaha, never heard of that time limit before, so I never answered that fast either.

Comment: no prob, just glad I could help. At first it seemed like a pretty hard one to fix

Answer (score 0):

Open the cmd and type this command

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

MariaDB will open in cmd, now type the following query in the MariaDB

```
UPDATE mysql.user 
SET authentication_string = password('your_password_here'),    
    plugin = 'mysql_native_password' 
WHERE user = 'root';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This works for me to enter into phpAdmin login page

Cheers!